# Laravel using the wrong user provider

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

We have two types of users, "users," who use the default Laravel auth scaffolding; and "members," who log in on a separate site that sets a cookie, which we read their member ID from and log them in using a separate auth provider.

The problem, which I haven't been able to replicate, is that we're getting an exception that appears to be triggered by the wrong user provider being used. The ExUserProvider retrieveByCredentials method gets the username and password, which it isn't expecting, and not the uniqueid, which it needs. Right now I'm just logging that the right information is missing. I can just do a return from there, but I don't know if that will cause other issues. (Especially given that I can't replicate it.)

Is there anything obviously wrong in the set-up below? Do you have any ideas on how to try and replicate this issue?

Auth Service Provider:

```
public function boot() {
    $this->registerPolicies();

    \Auth::provider('exdriver', function($app, array $config) {
        return new ExUserProvider();
    });
}
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'sso' => [
      'driver' => 'session',
      'provider' => 'ex',
    ],
],

... 

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'exusers' => [
      'driver' => 'exdriver',
      'model' => App\ExUser::class,
    ],

],
```

ExUserProvider

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $parameters) {

    if(!isset($parameters['uniqueid'])) {
        \Log::info('No uniqueid set when retrieveByCredentials in ExUserProvider');
        \Log::info($parameters);
        // return;
    }
    $exUser = new ExUser($parameters['uniqueid'], $parameters);

    //store the user
    session(['exuser' => $exUser]);


    return $exUser;

}

/**
 * Validate credentials.
 *
 * @param Authenticatable $user
 * @param array $credentials username and password
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials) {
    return TRUE;
}

/**
 * Retrieve stored user.
 *
 * @param type $identifier
 * @return string
 */
public function retrieveById($identifier) {
    return session('exuser', null);
}

public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {

}

public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, looks like some of the users must have had a reeeeally old version of the authentication cookie that didn't have their uniqueid in it. Clearing their cache made it so they could log in. Never would have thought of that!

Comment: Which cache are you talking about? I'm having the same kind of problem, on the auth.php file the user provider is some Customer class, but in production it is using the User class...locally I don't have this issue, same branch..I've compared the files and they are the same (prod and local branch)..